# Trisquel:What to type when I set a blank password?

Tags: login, password, trisquel

I recently installed trisquel on my computer. When I decided to use the terminal and sudo I was prompted to use a password despite the fact that I set a blank one.

I want to know what I am supposed to type then.

I am open to going into grub and somehow replacing the password.

I have tried out pressing enter at the terminal to no avail.

I am the root user and cannot make changes without the password.

Answer (score 0):

Just hit the ENTER key when prompt to a password. Or you can supply it like:

```
echo -e '\n' | sudo -S ls
```

Comment: Did you actually try this? `sudo` does not read the password from standard input.

Comment: Sorry. It didn't work.

Comment: Yes, I tried @JohanMyréen. The -S flag is exactly to read the password from standard input as stated by the manual. If entering an empty password isn't working I'd suggest then to change it. Boot your computer in single mode user (https://askubuntu.com/questions/132965/how-do-i-boot-into-single-user-mode-from-grub) , that will get you a shell as root. Then `passwd nitta` (supposing your username is nitta) would do the trick

Comment: @FredericoOliveira I'll try that out and report back